# Copy multiple rows from one worksheet to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Copy multiple rows from one worksheet to another worksheet

I have a query, i have one workbook which has got around 21 columns and around 1000 rows..However i just need 4 columns

for example

let says work book A has got these columns vmware ,powerstate, dns,cpyu,memory,ssid,disk,....Here i just need vmware ,powerstate,cpu,memory and disk on workbook b.

I have tried pivot table. it just went haywire.I have a bit of vb.which i am not sure where it landed.

can any one help

Comment: Provide the VB you've got so far and a specific problem, people won't write a solution from scratch for you.

Comment: i dont want the vb code.Is there any other way in excel that i could do that..

Comment: you cannot do a copy/paste with just formulas. You would need vba

Comment: ok here goes nothing. i followed this link

https://www.exceltrainingvideos.com/copy-paste-multiple-rows-of-data-from-one-workbook-to-another-using-excel-vba/

Comment: Why did that not work for you?

Comment: it did not change the values in another workgroup

Comment: post your code here to the question.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and the [help/on-topic]. Know how to put together a [mcve], *then* ask. This site isn't a code repository or developer discussion/brainstorming forum, it's Q&A, meant to be useful to people having *specific* issues and landing here from, say, a Google search. This question helps no one. Read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513) too.

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow If Cells(i, 2) = "Powerstate" Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Select Selection.Copy Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\slohith\Desktop\reports\santaclara.xlsx" Dim p As Integer, q As Integer p = Worksheets.Count For q = 1 To p If  activeWorkbook.Worksheets(q).Name = "Powerstate" Then
Worksheets("Powerstate").Select End If , Next q

Comment: that is half of the code

Comment: Instead of posting in a comment, where it's heard to read, can you post the code in your OP? And format with the code tags `{}`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy rows using the following VBA Code

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name Of Your Source Sheet").Columns(1).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name Of The Destination Sheet").Columns(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Replace the 1 in **Columns(1)** in the first line by the number of the column you want to copy in your source sheet.

Replace the 1 in **Columns(1)** in the second line by the number of the column you want to paste your copied column.